# Admob House Ad only when no fill

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am struggling with Admob fill rates. Fill rates in some countries (like UAE, Pakistan) is ver very low - sometimes it is as low as 20%.

I am concerned about this low fill rate and to address it, I have configured house ads with ecpm as $0.01 assuming that unfull-filled requests would display house ads. Both text ads (for banners) and image ads (for interestial) have been configured as house ads.

Low ecpm is to ensure that house ads are displayed only when there is no inventory / ads available with Admob.

However, the house-ads are also not getting displayed. The fill rates is still very poor. I failed to understand why?

1. Is it that house ads are not configured properly. Do i need to change the ecpm value?
2. Do house ads improve the fill rate?
3. Is it that in some countries Admob doesn't have too many advertisers? Should I switch to some other ad network?
4. Will mediation help?

Thanks in advance for the help. I have gone thru so much of documentation online but still not able to understand what is causing such a low fill rate.

Regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about advertising, not programming. Please contact your advertising network for assistance with using that advertising network.